# Swagger-ui shows date-time example in wrong format

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have this field in my DTO:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DateFormatPattern.ISO8601_DATE_TIME_UTC)
private Date collectionDate;
```

I declared this date format:

```
public class DateFormatPattern {
    public static final String ISO8601_DATE_TIME_UTC = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
}
```

When I build OpenAPI documentation, I get this example:

```
"collectionDate": "2021-06-28T12:45:13.491Z"
```

I added this annotation:

```
    @Schema(pattern = DateFormatPattern.ISO8601_DATE_TIME_UTC)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DateFormatPattern.ISO8601_DATE_TIME_UTC)
    private Date collectionDate;
```

But the result is the same. How can I add the right example(date in the format exactly like in the DTO)?